# Where does Django REST Swagger generate a schema file?

Tags: django, rest, swagger, api-doc, django-swagger

I want to modify the Swagger documentation generated by Django REST Swagger. I'd like to find the API definition or schema file(s) that Django REST Swagger generates. I haven't been able to find those files.

Is there something like a YAML or JSON file generated when Django REST Swagger creates API documentation?

Where can I find that file on the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no static files on the server.

Swagger generates the documentation based on [rest-framework internal schema representation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/).

So if you want to change the representation, you should replace swagger [templates](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/tree/master/rest_framework_swagger/templates) or js files. If you want to change the content of the documentation(some kind of string replacements etc.) you should preprocess schemas object before render in your [schema_view](http://marcgibbons.github.io/django-rest-swagger/).